# Qual è lo stato attuale della "ó"?

Tags: accents

Al di fuori di dizionari e simili, esiste qualche testata o editore che faccia un uso anche sporadico della "ó"?

*(se non ho inteso male, non esiste nessun caso in cui è obbligatoria, dunque l'unico uso possibile è se si vuole a tutti i costi disambiguare termini quali bótte e bòtte)*

Comment: Probabilmente trattasi di un'altra delle povere vittime del diabolico layout italiano delle tastiere. (RIP, È, É, etc.)

Comment: @badp in parte sì, d'altra parte se davvero non era obbligatorio da nessuna parte, si starebbe comunque estinguendo. Detto questo, appunto mi chiedo se qualcuno comunque lo stia usando.

Answer (score 3):

There *can* be some cases where `ó` should be used: if one wants to reproduce the French pronunciation, *bordó* would be better than *bordò* to mean the wine; nowadays the French spelling seems to be preferred (see the [entry in the Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bordo_res-a2efc577-0011-11de-9d89-0016357eee51/))

Perhaps a ‘more Italian’ word in the same situation is *borderó*, but of course its pronunciation is influenced by the fact that all Italian words ending in tonic *o* have the open sound. Dictionaries spell it as *borderò*.

Distinguishing between *bòtte* and *bótte* in written language seems not to be so important, the context will make it clear if punches or barrels are involved.

Comment: Sometimes the norms of Italian orthography win over the French sources. Indeed, the dictionaries record “bordò”, just like the italian word for a kind of milkshake is “frappè”, even if in French the past participle of “frapper” is “frappé”.

Comment: @DaG oh lol, I had no idea where the term _frappè_ came from.

Answer (score 1):

Non mi è mai capitato di vedere usata ó, a meno naturalmente non si abbia un nome spagnolo come Pedro Almodóvar.

Einaudi continua a usare í e ú (foneticamente più corrette di ì e ù), ma credo sia l'unico editore.